# How to to open file with searchmonkey?

Tags: searchmonkey

When I try to open a file after i do my search using searchmonkey app, it doesn't work. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use search monkey toolbar and go to Settings/Preferences/System Calls.

There you should choose your favorite text editor, for example gedit:

[image]

Bonus: you can add folder explorer and browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and eventually found that adding [xdg-open](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) as the Default text editor worked.